# Delete and Update a query from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am making a web application using ASP.NET and SQL Server data base. The error is that I can't delete nor update. I believe that the application doesn't get back the id of the selected column. My code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestClientesConnectionString %>"            
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Clientes]"             
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Clientes] SET [nombre]=@nombre, [apellidos]=@apellidos, [telefono]=@telefono, [fechaNacimiento]=@fechaNacimiento WHERE [ID]=@original_ID"
  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Clientes] WHERE [ID]=@original_ID"
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Clientes] VALUES (@nombre, @apellidos, @telefono, @fechaNacimiento)">
  <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
  </DeleteParameters>
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
  </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True">
  <Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="nombre" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="apellidos" HeaderText="Apellidos" SortExpression="apellidos" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="telefono" HeaderText="Telefono" SortExpression="telefono" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fechaNacimiento" HeaderText="Fecha Nacimiento" SortExpression="fechaNacimiento" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
  </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I have used different ways, but I can't solve the error. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your parameter name original_ID, if you use ID it should work. You are not changing the ID so there is no need to have a original_id